# Web Api controller of a webforms not working to POST verb

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Since I am a newbie in webAPI , I Searched so many questions regarding this, but nothing matches my case.
I have a webApi controller in webforms project.In the Post Method, some data is inserted into the DB. I had done this by taking instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms). Done Everything as they mentioned but the POST method of the controller is not working

**Note:-**
1) If i use Webservice(SOAP) with same codes instead of webAPI it works fine.
2) If I use postman  for testing its works.
3) If I use simple html page for Front End it shows **HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**

Here is my aspx page

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <input type="text" id="lastname" />
        <button id="submit"></button>

        <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {

                var appointment = {};
                appointment.FirstName = $('#name').val();
                appointment.LastName = $('#lastname').val();



                $.ajax({

                    url: '/api/Appointment',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'app': appointment }),
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,err)
                {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public class AppointmentController : ApiController
    {

        // POST api/<controller>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]Appointment app)
        {
            app.Save();
        }

    }
```

Here is the Global.asax

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
        }
    }
```

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="server=MACLINKSERVER\MSSQL_DEV;Database=DB_A1DE96_Smartgdx;UID=sa;PWD=123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: hi ..are in the same host? ..webform and webapi run on same localhost:port ?

Comment: can you jsu tru to do :  JSON.stringify(appointment)

Comment: Yes both are in same host.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi any hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the appointment

```
data: JSON.stringify(appointment),
```

as that is what the action is expecting.

Also the action needs to return a valid response as demonstrated in the documentation linked in the original question.

```
public class AppointmentController : ApiController {
    // POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Appointment app) {
        app.Save();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The assumption here is also that `Appointment` has a parameterless constructor that will allow the model binder to properly bind and populate the model.

Comment: I didnt had a parameterless constructor for the appointment model. Thanks @Nkosi